# Get active on the Meta -- help build Islam.SE

Tags: discussion, meta

The Meta site is very important to all StackExchange Sites.  It would seem that very few users are really active on the Meta site, and it is usually the Moderators, or some active user on the Main site.  I have observed that sometimes new users (usually the ones that get 5 reputation which is the required amount of rep to participate on Meta) come in say "wow I haven't been here before" then leave and most of the time don't come back, at least not some time soon.

It is very important for the Meta site to stay active, it was very important when Islam.SE launched into beta, and it is still very important.  My intention in writing this post is to help users (especially those who are new to StackExchange) realize how important Meta is.  Perhaps this post will catch the attention of someone new coming into the meta than about to leave, Allah knows best.

The Meta site is a place, connected to the main site, where a user can ask questions about the site (Islam.SE).

> Meta isn't [a random discussion area](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/faq), it is for improving our
>   community and site together.

Meta is the place where you can get what you think should change out.  The Meta site is the place where the rules and guidelines on how to use the main site (Islam.SE) are born.  It is the place to ask questions like:

- Is this question on topic?
- Why was my question closed?
- Should this question be reopened?

The more active the meta site is, the faster and better our community and site is built.  Look around on meta and see if your question or request hasn't been posted before.  If you want to help build this site, then Meta is the first place to start.

Comment: I think you should tag it as "featured" so it may appear in the Community Bulletin.